# Windows: folder created with nodejs - Windows says location not available

Tags: node.js, windows, location

I created a folder with nodejs (on Windows 10). The folder appears both on Windows file explorer and in command line. But when I click on iy, I have a location not available popup message. I did this on disk C and D, same problem. I cannot delete it either, neither via File explorer, no via nodejs fs.rmdir command (both saying no such file or directory)

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Perhaps there is a permission issue where the permissions it was created with are different than when you're trying to use it.

Comment: Can you share the full path of the folder? Maybe it contains forbidden name parts?

Comment: @ vsemozhebuty, as a matter of fact the directory name is "Shenzhen Zhiyuan Weiye Technology Co., Ltd." , I tried with Shenzhen-Zhiyuan-Weiye-Technology-Co-Ltd, and I have no problem. Now I wishI can find a way to get rid of the junk folder.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows, file or folder names with a dot or a space at the end are forbidden (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file). They can be created via some low-level ways (including Node.js — for example, `fs.mkdirSync('test.')`), but they will have issues with GUI or cli file system tools.

You can delete such directory via Node.js (`fs.rmdirSync('test.')` — works at least in the last Node.js release) or using special UNC name format: `rmdir \\?\c:\temp\test.`